# group by and sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning on the Northwind database. I found how many times each product has been sold in each region with this query:

```
     select R.RegionID
                  , R.RegionDescription
                  , P.ProductID
                  , P.ProductName
                  , sum(OD.Quantity) as SoldQuantity
    from Region as R inner join Territories as T on R.RegionID = T.RegionID
                     inner join EmployeeTerritories as ET on T.TerritoryID = ET.TerritoryID
                     inner join Employees as E on ET.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
                     inner join Orders as O on E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
                     inner join [Order Details] as OD on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
                     inner join Products as P on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
    group by R.RegionID, R.RegionDescription, P.ProductID, P.ProductName
```

but I struggle to extract ones with maximum 'SoldQuantity'(with their ProductID and ProductName) for each region.

I managed to find 'MaxSoldQuantity' for each region with this query:

```
    select NESTED.RegionID
         , NESTED.RegionDescription
         , max(NESTED.SoldQuantity) as MaxSoldQuantity
    from (
        select R.RegionID as RegionID
                    , R.RegionDescription as RegionDescription
                    , P.ProductID as ProductID
                    , P.ProductName as ProductName
                    , sum(OD.Quantity) as SoldQuantity
        from Region as R inner join Territories as T on R.RegionID = T.RegionID
                         inner join EmployeeTerritories as ET on T.TerritoryID = ET.TerritoryID
                         inner join Employees as E on ET.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
                         inner join Orders as O on E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
                         inner join [Order Details] as OD on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
                         inner join Products as P on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
        group by R.RegionID, R.RegionDescription, P.ProductID, P.ProductName
    ) as NESTED
    group by NESTED.RegionID, NESTED.RegionDescription
```

but whenever I add 'NESTED.ProductID' and 'NESTED.ProductName' to select and group by I get the same results as in the first query.

So my question is : How can I get the data about which product has been the most sold in each region ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should join the nested  Query for obtaion the ProductName and the ProductID

```
   select T1.RegionID
        , T1.RegionDescription 
        , T1.MaxSoldQuantity
        , N2.ProductName
        , N2.ProductID
   from (
      select NESTED.RegionID
         , NESTED.RegionDescription
         , max(NESTED.SoldQuantity) as MaxSoldQuantity
      from (
        select R.RegionID as RegionID
                    , R.RegionDescription as RegionDescription
                    , P.ProductID as ProductID
                    , P.ProductName as ProductName
                    , sum(OD.Quantity) as SoldQuantity
        from Region as R inner join Territories as T on R.RegionID = T.RegionID
                         inner join EmployeeTerritories as ET on T.TerritoryID = ET.TerritoryID
                         inner join Employees as E on ET.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
                         inner join Orders as O on E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
                         inner join [Order Details] as OD on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
                         inner join Products as P on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
        group by R.RegionID, R.RegionDescription, P.ProductID, P.ProductName
    ) as NESTED
    group by NESTED.RegionID, NESTED.RegionDescription ) T1
  inner join (
     select R.RegionID as RegionID
                  , R.RegionDescription as RegionDescription
                  , P.ProductID as ProductID
                  , P.ProductName as ProductName
                  , sum(OD.Quantity) as SoldQuantity
      from Region as R inner join Territories as T on R.RegionID = T.RegionID
                       inner join EmployeeTerritories as ET on T.TerritoryID = ET.TerritoryID
                       inner join Employees as E on ET.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
                       inner join Orders as O on E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
                       inner join [Order Details] as OD on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
                       inner join Products as P on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
      group by R.RegionID, R.RegionDescription, P.ProductID, P.ProductName
  ) N2 on N2.SoldQuantity = T1.MaxSoldQuantity
```

Comment: but 'MaxSoldQuantity' can't be accessed above the last line

Answer (score 2):

You don't give any sample data, so I can't test it.  But I think you can use window function to rank the `Quantity`.  The outermost query grab the max.

```
select *
from (
    select *
        , row_number over (partition by RegionID order by Quantity desc) as row_num
    from (
        select R.RegionID as RegionID
            , R.RegionDescription as RegionDescription
            , P.ProductID as ProductID
            , P.ProductName as ProductName
            , sum(OD.Quantity) as SoldQuantity
        from Region as R 
        inner join Territories as T on R.RegionID = T.RegionID
        inner join EmployeeTerritories as ET on T.TerritoryID = ET.TerritoryID
        inner join Employees as E on ET.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
        inner join Orders as O on E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
        inner join [Order Details] as OD on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
        inner join Products as P on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
        group by R.RegionID, R.RegionDescription, P.ProductID, P.ProductName
    ) nested
) ranked
where row_num = 1
```